# Count the possible extractions of numbered coloured balls from urns, with constant sum

Tags: combinatorics

I have 5 (coloured) urns.

The first urn is red and contains 11 red balls, numbered 0 to 10.

The second urn is yellow and contains 11 yellow balls, numbered 0 to 10.

Same goes for the third blue and fourth white urn.

The fifth and last urn, black, contains 9 balls, from 0 to 8.

I need a way to count the possible extractions of exactly one ball from each urn in such a way that the sum of the numbers on the balls gives 24.

These are my numbers but I am more interested in how to reason about this problem.

I start with just two urns, one with numbers from 0 to 5 and the other from 0 to 3. I need the way to extract two balls with sum, say, 6. The possible extractions are (5,1),(4,2) and (3,3).

I visualize this as the intersection of a line with a rectangle 6x4: I count hwo many integer lattice points are in the 2-D intersection and this gives me the solution.

I have a real hard time visualizing and solving this in 3-D, 4-D and so on: I need to count the lattice points in the volume that represent the intersection between all the possible extractions and the hyperplane that defines the desidered sum. 
I can't find a closed form that keeps into consideration the various constraints.

I use coloured balls because in my case the solution (a,b) is different from the solution (b,a)
Thanks

Comment: Generating functions will provide an answer: the coefficient of $x^{24}$ in the expansion of $\left(\dfrac{1-x^{11}}{1-x}\right)^4\left(\dfrac{1-x^{9}}{1-x}\right)$

Comment: If you didn't have upper bounds on the number of balls in each bin, this would simply be a [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.  The restrictions can be handled with the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) or, as Henry said, with [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 5$, denote the number on the ball extracted from urn $i$.  Then we want the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 24 \tag{1}$$
in the nonnegative integers subject to the restrictions that $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \leq 10$ and $x_5 \leq 8$.

A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of $5 - 1 = 4$ addition signs in a row of $24$ ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 $$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 6$, $x_4 = 9$, $x_5 = 5$.  The number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers is equal to the number of ways we can place four addition signs in a row of $20$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{24 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{28}{4}$$
since we must choose which four of the $28$ symbols required for $24$ ones and four addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

From these, we must subtract those cases in which one or more of the restrictions are violated.  Since $11 + 11 + 9 = 31 > 24$, at most two restrictions can be violated simultaneously.

Suppose $x_1 > 10$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 11$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 11 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 24\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 13 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with

> $$\binom{13 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{17}{4}$$

solutions.

By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions of equation 1 in which the restriction $x_i > 10$ is violated for each $i$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq 4$. Thus, there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{17}{4}$$

solutions of equation 1 in which one of the conditions $x_i > 10$, $1 \leq i \leq 4$ is violated.

If $x_5 > 8$, then $x_5' = x_5 - 9$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $x_5' + 9$ for $x_5$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5' + 9 & = 24\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5' & = 15 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with

> $$\binom{15 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{19}{4}$$

solutions.

Subtracting these cases from the total yields

> $$\binom{28}{4} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{17}{4} - \binom{19}{4}$$

If we subtract those solutions in which one of the restrictions is violated from the total, we will have subtracted those cases in which two of the restrictions are violated twice, once for each way of designating one of the restrictions as the one that has been violated.  Since we only want to subtract these cases once, we must add them back.

Suppose $x_1 > 10$ and $x_2 > 10$.  Then $x_1' = x_1 - 11$ and $x_2' = x_2 - 11$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ and $x_2' + 11$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 yields

\begin{align*}
x_1' + 11 + x_2' + 11 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 24\\
x_1' + x_2' + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 2 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
Equation 4 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with

> $$\binom{2 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{6}{4}$$

solutions.

By symmetry, the number of solutions in which $x_i, x_j > 10$, where $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$, is equal to the number of solutions in which $x_1, x_2 > 10$.

> Since there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways for two of the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ to exceed $10$, there are $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{4}$$ cases in which $x_i, x_j > 10$, where $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$.

If $x_1 > 10$ and $x_5 > 8$, then $x_1' = x_1 - 11$ and $x_5' = x_5 - 9$ are nonnegative integers.  Substituting $x_1' + 11$ for $x_1$ and $x_5' + 9$ for $x_5$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + 11 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5' + 9 & = 24\\
x_1' + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 & = 4 \tag{5}
\end{align*}
Equation 5 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with

> $$\binom{4 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{8}{4}$$

solutions.

By symmetry, there are an equal number of solutions of equation 1 in which $x_i > 10$ and $x_5 > 8$ for each $i$ such $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{4}$$

solutions in which $x_i > 10$ and $x_5 > 8$ for some $i$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq 4$.

Hence, there are

> $$\binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{4} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{4}$$

solutions of equation 1 in which two of the restrictions are violated.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of admissible solutions of equation 1 is

> $$\binom{28}{4} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{17}{4} - \binom{19}{4} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{6}{4} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{4}$$

The calculations would have been somewhat simpler if there were an equal number of balls in each urn.